# How to access property from class that extends T when getting generic Class<out T> in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, reflection

I have an abstract class called `Event` which has an abstract variable `handlers`. The class `MessageEvent` extends the `Event` class and initialises the `handlers` variable.
My plan is to have several different classes that extend `Event`, so this function takes a `Class<out Event>` generic type.
How do I access this initialised `handlers` variable when the class is passed to the function as a generic? My goal is to get something that works like Bukkit's plugin manager, I'm trying to create an events system that works like how it does, but in Kotlin.
The code for how Bukkit does this in Java is over here, mine is similar but in Kotlin https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/bukkit/browse/src/main/java/org/bukkit/plugin/SimplePluginManager.java. That file also has a method called getEventListeners which I'm trying to replicate.

Event class

```kotlin
abstract class Event {
    abstract var name: String?
    abstract var handlers: HandlerList

    public fun getEventName(): String {
        if (name == null) {
            name = javaClass.kotlin.simpleName as String
        }
        return name as String
    }


}
```

(Temporary) MessageEventClass

```kotlin
class MessageEvent(val content: String) : Event() {
    override var name: String? = "Message event"
    override var handlers: HandlerList = HandlerList()
}
```

From just passing along the class as a generic I want to access the handlers property.

```kotlin
    fun getEventListeners(event: Class<out Event>): HandlerList {

        // Something here to return the handlers variable of the the given event

    }
```

I've tried several reflection techniques but nohing has worked so far.

Setting the getHandlers getter function to accessible and invoking it resulted in an unhelpful NullPointerException.

```kotlin
    fun getEventListeners(event: Class<out Event>): HandlerList {
        var method: Method = event.getDeclaredMethod("getHandlers")
        method.setAccessible(true)
        return method.invoke(event.declaringClass) as HandlerList
    }
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at pet.nekos.api.plugin.PluginManager.getEventListeners(PluginManager.kt:175)
        at pet.nekos.api.plugin.PluginManager.registerEvents(PluginManager.kt:160)
        at pet.nekos.exampleplugin.ExamplePlugin.onEnable(ExamplePlugin.kt:15)
...
```

In guides I see they get a field called memberProperties from the class, but this doesn't seem to exist in my case, I'm guessing because it's a generic.

I think I will have to use reflection for this, but I've tried a lot and haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: [`getDeclaringClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaringClass()) returns the outer class of a nested class or `null`, as in your case, when the class is not a nested class. It’s not clear why you decided to use `event.declaringClass`; to invoke the method, you need an object of type `Event`.

Comment: I don't really follow why you are even using `Class<out Event>` here. Why not make the parameter type simply `Event`?

Comment: The `Event` class itself never gets used, how can I still make sure it'll accept any class that extends it?

Comment: The reason the Event type isn't known is it's retrieved from an argument in a function. So I get it by using a for loop for all methods from something that wants to register to this event, and then get it with `method.ParameterTypes[0]`. So alternatively, how can I turn that returned `Class<*>` from that into an Event? I made it into a `Class<out Event>` with `checkClass.asSubclass(Event::class.java)`, but I'm not sure what I should be doing instead if I'm not using `Class<out Event>`

Comment: This is not really about whether Event is known or not. You try to acquire `handlers`, which is an instance property, from `Class` which is not even an instance. It is just a class. This is like this code: `MessageEvent.handlers`. You can't expect it holds any real data. It definitely sounds like you should receive just `Event`, not `Class`. It will work with `MessageEvent` properly.

Comment: Alright I see thanks, still not sure how I can get the MessageEvent with its properties from how I get it from the parameter types of a method, but will try some things.

Comment: After looking more I'm pretty sure I need to use a companion object for this, the handlers variable shouldn't be tied to any one instance of the class. I've changed that, still have to find a way to access it though, still using `Class<out Event>` because of how I obtain that class and don't see how I can change that yet

Comment: I wanted the handlers variable to be independent from any one instance of the class. I needed to create a companion object, after creating a companion object I was able to invoke the retrieved method with null.

Comment: It doesn't matter if `Event` class isn't use. If you define the parameter just as `Event` it also accepts any class that extends it. that's how extending works. Each subclass of `Event` is still an event. I really think you need to do that